# JSXGraph doubles-up displaying of axis labels

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

JSXGraph seems to double up displaying axis labels when graphs are rescaled. Does anyone know of a fix to this problem?

To replicate, use

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {axis:true});
board.setBoundingBox([-6,3,3,-3]);
```

This results in the '-4' on the x-axis displaying twice, overlapping itself.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vsn18x9p/3/

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt9fo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It is already fixed in the latest nightly builds.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you set the boundingbox when you create the board the issue does not occur. You can also update the bounding box later without the issue occurring.

So the working code would be

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {axis:true,boundingbox:[-6,3,3,-3]});
board.setBoundingBox([-8,3,3,-3]);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybjenvac/

Hope that helps someone!